# trying to clamscan my drive, error in permissions

Tags: clamav

My computer's been slowing down.  I want to scan it for viruses.  I made a text file for a log as /home/user/Infected/clamscanlog
I ran:
clamscan -i -r --log=/$home/USER/Infected/clamscanlog

and I get
ERROR: Can't open //USER/Infected/clamscanlog in append mode (check permissions!).
ERROR: Problem with internal logger.

I tried the whole thing again with sudo in front and got the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that Unix/Linux cares about case (UPPER,lower) and that environment variables have an initial `$`, and their values. See `echo "$HOME"; echo "$USER"`.

```
--log=$HOME/infected/clamscanlog
```

Comment: Thank you.  Will this scan my drive or just the folders in the home directory?  Is it necessary to run this with sudo?

Comment: Read `man clamscan` and don't ask a 2nd question in the comments.